# Exception NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

tried to implement a simple example to parse html

failure:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at html_parser.JSoupBsp.main(JSoupBsp.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

MyCode:

```
package html_parser;


import java.io.IOException; 
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JSoupBsp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
            // Dokument von URL laden
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.javabeginners.de").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(doc.title());            
         
    }
}
```

Project props:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHR1X.png)

So I don't know why it does not work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think if you were to just take the back part of the util and use it in the forefront of the code.

It would release the lock gate and let you connect the layouts in a passive way.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're saying or why.